# flash and html: is there a flash iframe equivalent?

Tags: html, flash

hey guys,
probably weird question, i'm just curious.

Is there any way to kind of load a HTML website into a Flash-object. Imagine it like an iframe for flash. A full flash website is loaded, and when a button is clicked an entire HTML document gets loaded inside the flash object.

It's probably not working, however i'm just nosy to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [HTMLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html) which can display html and execute JavaScript, but it's AIR only. I guess Webkit doesn't fit into Flash installer, which is under 3 MB :)

Answer (score 0):

There is integration between Flex and regural iframe http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/